# Trying to display the ints in an array that only occur once

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array I have created that is a length of 25 and and has randomly generated numbers in it 1 to 25.  The array will pretty much always have duplicate numbers in it and all i want to do is display the numbers that occur only once in the array. The code I have so far seems to work as long as the numbers that are repeated only repeat an even number of times.  My question is how do I make this work so I only get numbers that occur once added to my string.

I can not use hash or set or anything like that this is part of an assignment.

```
int count2 = 0;

for (int d = 0; d < copy.length-1; d++) 
{
    int num = copy[d];

    if (num != copy[d+1]) 
    {
        s = s + "," + num;
    } 
    else 
    {
        d++;
    }    
}
```

Comment: This would only find two consecutive duplicates...what if the duplicate occurs further along...are you interested in those too?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26803666/how-to-remove-duplicate-numbers-in-an-array/26803885#26803885

Comment: Do you care about the order? If not, sort the array first, then apply your approach. (And don't `+` strings, use a `StringBuilder`.)

Answer (score 1):

Use a [HashSet!](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html)

1. Construct two new HashSets, one for the elements appearing just once and one for the duplicates
2. Iterate through your array
3. For each value in the array check if it's already in the set of duplicates. If so, do nothing else and continue to the next iteration
4. Check if the value is already in the set of elements appearing just once
5. If it's not, add it. If it is, remove it and add it to a list of duplicates
6. Call hashSet.toArray() and then you will have an array of all the elements appearing only once
7. You can convert the array to a string or use it however you wish

This approach is very efficient as search, insert, and remove are all O(1) in a HashSet.

Comment: ah okay, well best of luck :)

Answer (score 1):

I would start by writing a separate method to count the number of occurrences of a value in the given array so you can `count` how many occurrences there are for each `value` using a [`For-Each` Loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) like

```
private static int count(int[] arr, int value) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int item : arr) {
        if (item == value) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Then you can leverage that like

```
public static String toUniqueString(int[] arr) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int value : arr) {
        if (count(arr, value) == 1) {
            if (sb.length() != 0) {
                sb.append(", ");
            }
            sb.append(value);
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Finally, to test it

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int[] arr = new int[25];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = rand.nextInt(arr.length) + 1;
    }
    System.out.println(toUniqueString(arr));
}
```

Comment: I am unsure of what you mean by value.

Comment: @johnodom Please don't make the [same edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8083760) [multiple times](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8084228), also an edit to your preferred coding style isn't necessary.